# How do I properly handle all possible exceptions by the requests module if a site is not reachable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking, python-requests

I live in China, behind the infamous Great Firewall of China, and I use VPNs.

A simple observation is that while the VPN is connected, I can access [www.google.com](http://www.google.com). And if the VPN isn't connected, then I cannot access Google. So I can check if I have an active VPN connection by accessing Google.

My ISP really loves to disconnect my VPN, and so I have routinely check if I have an active VPN connection, and I have already found a way to programmatically do this.

I am connected to the VPN right now, and if I do the following:

```py
import requests

google = requests.get('https://www.google.com', timeout=3)
print(google.status_code == 200)
```

Everything is fine.

But if I don't have an active VPN connection, then all hell breaks loose.

I do this check precisely because my connection will be disconnected, and I need a function to return a `False` when it happens, but `requests` really loves to throw exceptions, it stops the execution of my script, and the exceptions come one after another:

```
...
ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.google.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=3)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ReadTimeout                               Traceback (most recent call last)
...
```

I have imported a bunch of exceptions just so `requests` doesn't panic and stop my script when VPN is disconnected:

```py
import requests
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError, ConnectTimeout, ReadTimeout, Timeout
from socket import gaierror
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import MaxRetryError, NewConnectionError, ReadTimeoutError

def google_accessible():
    try:
        google = requests.get('https://www.google.com', timeout=3)
        if google.status_code == 200:
            return True
    except (ConnectionError, ConnectTimeout, gaierror, MaxRetryError, NewConnectionError, ReadTimeout, ReadTimeoutError, TimeoutError):
        pass
    return False
```

I thought I caught all exceptions previously, but that isn't the case because I failed to catch the above exceptions (`ReadTimeout`, `ReadTimeoutError`, `TimeoutError`).

I know I can use `except Exception` to catch them all, but that would catch exceptions that aren't intended to be caught, and I would rather let those exceptions stop the execution than risking bugs.

How do I use minimal number of exceptions to catch all exceptions that are VERY likely to occur when a request failed?

Comment: For your information I can use [evpn](https://pypi.org/project/evpn/)'s `ExpressVpnApi.is_connected` to check if the VPN thinks it's connected, but that doesn't update as frequently as needed, and it often reports false positives when I cannot access Google.

Comment: Maybe want to be careful about disclosing your purpose for VPNs at the beginning. Just a thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it would be better to use `RequestException` from `requests.exception` module. The hierarchy is the following:

```
builtins.OSError(builtins.Exception)
    RequestException  # <- Use this top level exception
        ChunkedEncodingError
        ConnectionError
            ConnectTimeout(ConnectionError, Timeout)
            ProxyError
            SSLError
        ContentDecodingError(RequestException, urllib3.exceptions.HTTPError)
        HTTPError
        InvalidHeader(RequestException, builtins.ValueError)
        InvalidJSONError
            JSONDecodeError(InvalidJSONError, json.decoder.JSONDecodeError)
        InvalidSchema(RequestException, builtins.ValueError)
        InvalidURL(RequestException, builtins.ValueError)
            InvalidProxyURL
        MissingSchema(RequestException, builtins.ValueError)
        RetryError
        StreamConsumedError(RequestException, builtins.TypeError)
        Timeout
            ReadTimeout
        TooManyRedirects
        URLRequired
        UnrewindableBodyError
builtins.Warning(builtins.Exception)
    RequestsWarning
        FileModeWarning(RequestsWarning, builtins.DeprecationWarning)
        RequestsDependencyWarning
```

So you can do:

```
from requests.exception import RequestException

def google_accessible():
    try:
        google = requests.get('https://www.google.com', timeout=3)
        if google.status_code == 200:
            return True
    except RequestException:
        pass
    return False
```

Comment: I failed to find `gaierror` in the hierachy, does it catch `socket.gaierror` as well? I assume not. In any case it reduced the number of exceptions I need to import to at most two.

Comment: From the documentation, All [socket exception](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#exceptions) subclass OSError exception: *Errors related to socket or address semantics raise OSError or one of its subclasses.* but catch OSError seems too broad IMHO.